# Jquery Disable Validation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to disable validation some textboxes when certain button is clicked for instance , If i have got 4 textboxes , when I click button 1 only first 2 textbox should validate and when I click button 2 only the last 2 textboxes should validate , Currently all the boxes are validating , How can i enable / disable textbox validation using jquery , The validation only activate on the textboxes which are visible in the UI not the hidden one I googled it and found some thing like this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("YourbuttonID").disableValidation = true;
</script>
```

Below is the code which I am using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $startdates = $('#startDates');
    var $endDates = $('#endDates');
    var $showEvents = $('#showEvents');
    $startdates.hide();
    $endDates.hide();
    $showEvents.hide();

    $('#hide').click(function () {
        $startdates.show();
        $endDates.show();
        $('#showEvents').show();
        $('#eventdids').hide();

        $(this).hide();
        return false;

    });

    $("#hide").validate({
        ignore: "#hide"
    })

    $('#showEvents').click(function () {
        $startdates.hide();
        $endDates.hide();

        $('#eventdids').show();
        $('#hide').show();
        $(this).hide();
        return false;

    });
});
 </script>
<tr id="startDates">
        <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="endDates">
        <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate) %>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
<tr id="eventdids">
        <td>
        <label>Events</label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <% foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewData["events"]) { %>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="<%=item.Value %>" />
                  <label for="<%=item.Value%>"><%=item.Text%></label>
                  <br />

        <% } %> 

        </td>
        <td><input type="button" name="Select" id="hide" style="width:auto" value="Select All Events" /></td>


        </tr>

        </table>
      <input type="button" name="show" id="showEvents" style="width:auto" value="Show All Events" />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wouldn't play with hiding elements + it will fail at the server validation - these fields are still required according to your model

you will have to create a dependent validation for handling both cases 
this might help you[conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukadc/archive/2011/02/10/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)